# Greeting in an Email Autoresponse: 您好， 亲爱的 or something else?

Tags: word-choice, greetings

It's a pretty specific situation, so I hope you can help me.

Comment: Depends on clientele, of course. The popular way to address people these days, especially in a business setting, is just a simple: **亲**. This might seem tacky though, depending on who you are dealing with.

Comment: I think the safest way is 您好, as 您 is the respectable version of you and works for males and females.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and safest way:

```
您好，
```

If your email auto response included name(from email or etc):

```
Franjo Tušek， 
             您好，
```

Comment: Do not put "您好" together with name in one line.

Comment: forgot to mention, you have to put it on next line. I thought i already enter it to the next line. i will edit it. thanks @XiaogeSu

Comment: Now I got curious of what's the problem of putting them on the same line. Why not?

Comment: First line can only have either name or greetings.

Answer (score 1):

To business client its best to use

```
尊敬的客户(or person's lastname followed by 小姐/女士/先生):
   您好!
   (Content)

   再次感谢您对我行一贯的支持与厚爱.
   (or 再次感谢您给我们提供沟通交流的机会，祝您家庭幸福，年年安康！)
   谢谢!  


                                           (Your name, Company)    
                                                     2015年1月
```

To family and friends you can use

```
亲爱的姐姐:
    你最近好吗?
    (Content)


                                                     爱你的弟弟
                                                     2015年1月
```

尊敬的 is formal, (used in email response to your boss, elder)
亲爱的 is less formal, if you know the client you are responding to, you can use 亲爱的

Comment: This is a question about _auto-responses_. That means by definition that you cannot know who you're writing to, or indeed what the context is. The greeting, as well as the content, should be as generic as possible.

Comment: 亲爱的 usually implies some kind of personal relationship, e.g. writing to parents, children, etc.